# How to execute a php file when a cron job is created

Tags: php, cron

I want one of my **PHP** file to be *executed* when the cron job is executed. I want to do this for updating the database of every users. It is a Banking application project and I need to update every user's account with interest amount. Any other possible approach/suggestion welcomed.

Comment: `* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script`

Comment: @MarcB — That is running a PHP script as a cron job, not running it when a cron job is created.

Comment: My website is hosted. Is `/usr/bin/php` will work? coz its shows something like: `/home/jnstech`

Comment: you want to keep track of who's setting cron jobs? not really possible without a lot of hacking. e.g. monitoring crontab files, wrapping the cron executable, blah blah blah.

Comment: I'm sorry. But I'm unable to understand your last comment @MarcB

Comment: Do you need to know what the change was to crontab? If not, just store the md5sum and setup a PHP cron job to check the md5sum for crontab every so often. If you do need the change, make a copy and every time you see a new md5sum, diff it with the current crontab.

Comment: @moha: you need to track/monitor/capture/wrap EVERY possible way a cron tab file can be changed. either via `crontab -e`, `vi /etc/cron.d/daily/etc...`. There are **MANY** places a cron job can be set. so, like I said, it's not really possible without a lot of hacking.

Comment: Okay @MarcB. it seems to be much tricky to handle `cron job`

Comment: @MohammadFaisal To make sure I've understood you, you want to run your php when the cron data is edited, not when the jobs are run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: running scheduled jobs (cron jobs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120228/php-running-scheduled-jobs-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no standard "A cron job has been created" hook, this would be  somewhat non-trivial.

I suppose you could hack cron and run your own custom build of it that would keep a history of the jobs it had seen and run the PHP script if it saw a new one.

Alternatively you could watch for changes to the various files/directories that cron jobs are stored in (e.g. `/var/spool/cron/` and `/etc/cron.*/`) using either [Inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) or its equivalent on your OS or a cronjob that looks for changes every few minutes.